# How to manage Core Data context when there could be updates of data in background?

Tags: ios, core-data, concurrency, nsmanagedobject, nsmanagedobjectcontext

I've been looking for posts related to this scenario, but I don't have a clear idea of how should I manage it: I have a context that could have several (maybe quite a lot) managed objects that the application may be using to perform operations, or even the user could be editing them, and meanwhile I can receive updates of the information in such objects from a service. Updating those objects while the user is editing them or the app is using them to perform operations and calculations could be a problem, as well as saving the context for the update received. I need somehow to "block" the objects being used when I concurrently need to save the updates I receive.

I hope I'm explaining the scenario clearly... how could/should I manage it?

Comment: This is a complex issue that entirely depends on your use case. The "Change Management" section of the Core Data Programming Guide goes into this in detail with several scenarios. https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdChangeManagement.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001201-CJBDBHCB

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want to do is handle server updates on a child context as defined in the latest Core Data Programming Guide.  Then set the merge policy on your main queue context to whatever makes sense for your business logic.

From there  you let Core Data handle the merges.  That is one of the primary features of Core Data.

Comment: I suppose that, in case data updates are long-running tasks, I should use a managed object context in a private queue... Should I then create a child context with private queue concurrency type? Or would creating a new "non-child" object context with private queue concurrency type be enough?

Comment: All data processing contexts should be private queues, always.  Never process data on a main queue context that will block the UI and give the user a poor experience. I prefer to use child contexts as it reduces the code complexity and performance impacts as opposed to having them as siblings.